# Bulk Png to SVG

Tags: python, svg, bitmap, png, vectorization

I need to batch convert Png files into SVG vectorized and traced files.

I need to transform 51.587 png files into svg.

Those files contained in 61115 subfolders, in a folder called "Folder1". The logos are simple to convert as they are 1-4 colors per png.

I tried python scripts with potrace and cairosvg however they don't seem to work as I was able to create svg files with the same name but they were empty.

I do not have any code knowledge.

I tried python scripts with potrace and cairosvg however they don't seem to work as I was able to create svg files with the same name but they were empty.

Comment: [SO] can help you troubleshoot existing code, not write it for you. To learn more about how the community can help you, please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a look at [`vtracer`](https://github.com/visioncortex/vtracer/tree/master/cmdapp/vtracer). Here is an example (and here are the [docs](https://www.visioncortex.org/vtracer-docs)):

```py
from pathlib import Path

import vtracer

root_folder = r"d:\temp\test"

for image in Path(root_folder).glob("**/*.png"):
    
    print(f"Process {image}")

    vectorized_image = image.with_suffix(".svg")

    vtracer.convert_image_to_svg_py(str(image), str(vectorized_image))
```

There are some parameters you could use to tweak the result; see [here](https://github.com/visioncortex/vtracer/tree/master/cmdapp/vtracer#usage-python).

Comment: Hey thomas, 

First of all thank you so much for trying to help me.

Second, I'm sorry you lost your work break on my problem.

Third, it looks like it might actually works well. Other than little tracing imperfections however if there is no optimized option this would definetly massively help me. Thank you again

Comment: There are some parameters you could use to tweak the result; see [here](https://github.com/visioncortex/vtracer/tree/master/cmdapp/vtracer#usage-python).